# Regarding Bluetooth Protocol

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, headset

Can Android app installed in tablet show alert for in-coming Call or SMS of any other device (Nokia,iPhone,Window) with it is paired by blue-tooth ?

What i am able to do -
I can pair android  device with any other device (Nokia,iPhone,Window) by blue-tooth protocol.
Now how can detect that there is In-coming call or SMS on device which is paired with ?

Anybody has idea for similar feature in android ?

Answer (score 0):

One way of implementing it is to write two applications one for each device which will communicate via bluetooth.
You will have to define and implement a protocol between the two devices. 
The application on the phone will register to listen for Intents for incoming call and incoming SMS. For example look at http://www.krvarma.com/2010/08/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-calls-in-android/

and

Once you receive these intents on the device then send information to other device through the defined prtotocol using bluetooth. For example you can use XML to communicate.

And then on the other device application you will show notifications using Activity.

I hope this helps